# VBA - Open a msgbox when cell value = 1

Tags: vba, excel, msgbox

I need help with a very basic vba macro. When the value in A6 is equal 1 a msgbox needs to appear in the workstation. I developed the below code but the problem is that when I add any other information in the spreadsheet (for example, if I write "i love pizza" in B6) the msgbox will prompt again and I need it to prompt just one time, just when I set the value of A6 = 1. Could you please help me?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Range("A6").Value = 1 Then
    MsgBox "THIS IS A MSGBOX."
End If

End Sub
```

@edit
I forgot one very important thing... the value "1" is getted with a VLOOKUP so its not insert manually by the user, i'm sorry about this. I tried the codes you people answered and it worked just when I put the vlue manually and as I said in the edit start, the value is set with a VLOOKUP. Any other tips, please?

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if the change is due to the cell A6 being changed, rather than a different cell.
Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = 1 And Target.Row = 6 Then
    If Target.Value = 1 Then
      MsgBox "THIS IS A MSGBOX."
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code instead of the previous one

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = Me.Range("A6").Address And Me.Range("A6").Value = 1 Then
        MsgBox "THIS IS A MSGBOX."
    End If
End Sub
```

Target is the changed cell in Excel. so for every change event, I check if the target is Range("A6").

Answer (score 2):

Pertaining to the statment : **and I need it to prompt just one time**, you need to save the oldvalue. So the prompt is displayed only once, when you set the value to 1. If A6 is already 1 and then you type 1 again, no prompt.

---

```
Option Explicit

Dim oldVal
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If (Target.Address = "$A$6") Then
        If Target.Value = 1 And Target.Value <> oldVal Then
            oldVal = Target.Value
            MsgBox "Test"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Rather than use a module-scope variable here, it may make sense to use a local-scope Static variable, i.e. declare the variable using "Static oldVal" within the subroutine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check inside the `Worksheet_Change` event, that only if Cell "A6" is pressed, then continue. And afterwards, check if the value of the cell equals 1.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A6")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target.Value = 1 Then MsgBox "THIS IS A MSGBOX."
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "$A$6" Then
        If Target.Value = 1 Then
            MsgBox "THIS IS A MSGBOX."
        End If
    End If    
End Sub
```

Comment: No, you mean `Target.Address= "$A$6"`

Answer (score 0):

I forgot one very important thing... the value "1" is getted with a VLOOKUP so its not insert manually by the user, i'm sorry about this. I tried the codes you people answered and it worked just when I put the vlue manually and as I said in the edit start, the value is set with a VLOOKUP. Any other tips, please?